# Yii2 redirect to login

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem with Yii2 Framework authentication in controller. When I send POST or GET it redirect to login page, which I dont want. I use dektrium\user. I want to send POST as guest. Last I have tried everyone nothing works. Login page is also showed, when I use Postman. 
Can you say me what is wrong?

**Controller**

```
class DhtController extends Controller implements ISensorController
{
public $enableCsrfValidation =false;

public function behaviors()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
        'authenticator' => [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                ['class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()],
                ['class' => QueryParamAuth::className(), 'tokenParam' => 'accessToken'],
            ]
        ],
        'exceptionFilter' => [
            'class' => ErrorToExceptionFilter::className()
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login', 'signup','last'],
            'roles' => ['?'],
        ],
    ]);
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = DhtData::find();

    $pagination = new Pagination(['defaultPageSize' => 15,
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);
    $dhts = $query->orderBy('id')
        ->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dhts' => $dhts,
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]);

}
   public function actionLast()
{
    if (\Yii::$app->request->isGet) {
        $max = DhtData::find()->max('id');
        $dht = DhtData::findOne($max);

        return $this->render('last', [
            'temp' => $dht->Temperature,
            'hum' => $dht->Humidity,
            'date' => $dht->Created_at
        ]);
    }

    if (\Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $data = Json::decode(\Yii::$app->request->getRawBody());

        if ($data) {
            $filter = new DhtSearch($data);
            $records = DhtData::find();
            if ($filter->beginDate)
                $records = $records->andWhere(['>=', 'Created_at', $filter->beginDate]);

            if ($filter->endDate)
                $records = $records->andWhere(['<=', 'Created_at', $filter->endDate]);

            $records = $records->asArray()->orderBy('Created_at DESC')->all();
            $max = $records[0];
            $json = JSON::encode($max);
        } else {
            $max = DhtData::find()->max('id');
            $dht = DhtData::findOne($max);
            $json = JSON::encode($dht);
        }
        \Yii::$app->response->content = $json;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure because it's hard to tell based only on this code you gave but isn't your behavior configuration wrong?

Shouldn't be:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
        'authenticator' => [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                ['class' => HttpBearerAuth::className()],
                ['class' => QueryParamAuth::className(), 'tokenParam' => 'accessToken'],
            ]
        ],
        'exceptionFilter' => [
            'class' => ErrorToExceptionFilter::className()
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login', 'signup','last'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: It redirect to login page on every action. There no behavior on base controller and commented I commented all rbac and user options at web.php — no result